# Custome wordpress plugin - table tag replaced by p tag in front page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

Hey guys I am creating a small datatable plugin and for some unknown reason, my HTML output seems to be stripped. The code I want to display is a simple datatable.

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'my_thank_you_text' );
function my_thank_you_text ( $content ) {
    $content .= '   
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ';
    return $content;
}
```

I would expect to see a table on the front page but instead I see the following:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>Column 1 Column 2 Row 1 Data 1 Row 1 Data 2 Row 2 Data 1 Row 2 Data 2</p>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Wordpress seems to be stripping down the HTML out of my $content. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the priority (thrid) parameter of `add_action`? Try setting it to 1 to see if that helps.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/ for more info.

Also, consider asking at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: After a lot of debug I cam to the conclusion that using a shortcode is better and does not have the same limitation. It solved my problem. Thanks for your time ;-)